# small confusion on $f'(x)=f'(-x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> I know it might be silly but I have a small confusion regarding this function

$f'(x)=f'(-x)$

we know that $f'(x)=f'(-x)$ is an even function so f(x) must be an odd function but in my textbook question it is written that is $f(x)$ is an even function then $f(x)=0$ for all real numbers according to me it is correct in my textbook it is written that it is an incorrect statement. please explain me why is it incorrect

Comment: So, the text asserts that if $f$ is both even and odd then it is constantly zero.  Your question is:  how is this true?

Comment: Also, saying "$f'(x)=f'(-x)$" is not a function.  That is an equality between two functions.  You cannot say that is even, but you can say that $f'$ is even, which means that $f'(x)=f'(-x)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $f$ is odd we have $f(x)=-f(-x)$ for any $x$.  But $f$ is also even, so from $f(-x)=f(x)$ the previous becomes $f(x)=-f(x)$.  Now we see that $f(x)=0$.  This is true for any $x$, so $f$ must be constantly $0$.

Comment: in my textbook it is written that f(x)=0 is an incorrect statement so is the thing written in my textbook wrong

Comment: It’s hard to say:  the original question is not clear.

Comment: This argument proves correctly that the only function that's both even and odd is the function that's identically 0. But the question seems to be about a function whose derivative is even. I wonder why the OP has accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

according to me if $f(x)$ is odd then it must be symmetric about the origin for it to be even it must be symmetric about the y-axis so for it to satisfy both the given conditions it must be 0 for all the real numbers.